# Reinstall Gallery app on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, installation, gallery

I accidently uninstalled the Gallery app that came with my Samsung Galaxy S3. I installed another gallery, but I cannot choose a photo for lock-screen.

Is it possible to reinstall the Gallery app? If it is, how do I do it?

Comment: What android version? And what rom?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use the Google Photos app, but yes, you can re-download it.

Here is a list of downloads for the S3 stock apps for Jellybean:

http://www.the-area51.com/2013/01/samsung-galaxy-s3-jellybean-stock-apks.html

Download the gallery apk file on your phone, and open it. A promt will open, click install. Once it's finished, you can delete the file you downloaded, and open the app like you normally would.